# There's no line break when I use an style I createad

Tags: text, format

I created this text style for using in my document:

```
\newcommand{\nosc}[1]{\text{\color{naranjaosc}#1}}
```

But when I use it, like here

```
Rotar un punto $P(x, y)$ con respecto a un \nosc{punto $C(x_0,y_0)$ distinto del origen} en un angulo $\alpha$ es equivalente a rotar el punto $Q(x-x_0,y-y_0)$ con respecto al origen en un ángulo $\alpha$ y luego sumar este resultado al punto C original.\\
```

the result is this one:

[image: Result of the style application]

¿Does anybody know how can I fix it? I have tried putting

```
\newcommand{\nosc}[1]{\text{\color{naranjaosc}#1}, breakable}
```

but it doesn't work :(

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome. Why `\text` in the first place? Remove it but leave the braces (or use `\textcolor{naranjaosc}{#1}`). The `breakable` ist just text, there is no concept of styles that way.

Comment: If I put that it only changes the color of the first letter of the phrase I put between the braces after \nosc

Comment: What you describe happens if you write `\textcolor{naranjaosc}#1`, but @Qrrbrbirlbel wrote in comment  `\textcolor{naranjaosc}{#1}` (with braces). So `\newcommand{\nosc}[1]{\textcolor{naranjaosc}{#1}}`.

Comment: use `{\color{red}...}` or `\textcolor{red}{...}` not `\text`{\color{red}...}`

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to TeX.SX! As suggested in the comments, you should not use `\text{}` here, beause this will create an unbreakable box and is not needed at all.

Also, you cannot add `breakable` to the macro just like this. You probably got this idea from the `tcolorbox` package, where you can add this as an option. But in a standard macro such as you define it, such has no defined meaning and will therefore only be parsed as text.

If you want to use the `\color` macro, note that it functions like a switch and takes no argument. So, everything after `\color{naranjaosc}` will have this color. You need to create a group using curly braces, such as `{\color{naranjaosc} some colored text}`.

Therefore a solution to your problem could be as follows (I changed the text a bit to make it break at the end of the line and also used another color because I did not know the exact definition):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{naranjaosc}{rgb}{1,.5,0}

\newcommand{\nosc}[1]{{\color{naranjaosc}#1}}

\begin{document}

Rotar cualquier punto $P(x, y)$ con respecto a un \nosc{punto $C(x_0,y_0)$ distinto del origen} en un angulo $\alpha$ es equivalente a rotar el punto $Q(x-x_0,y-y_0)$ con respecto al origen en un ángulo $\alpha$ y luego sumar este resultado al punto $C$ original.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Side note: Do not use `\\` at the end of a paragraph. Instead, just add a blank line, which has the same meaning as `\par`.